# Why multiprocessing.Pool gives so strange error in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Please give an advice, what to do. Can't understand what is going on. I want to run simple test script using multiprocessing.Pool in python.

I am running on windows, python 2.7

When i start my script, i see errors, that never end. I can't get what is going on. I copied a part of my big list:

```
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
AssertionError: thread
prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
      File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
        AssertionErrorprepare(preparation_data)
AssertionError  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
:   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
: prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
t  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
    t            hreadprepare(preparation_data)
hreadassert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
prepare(preparation_data)
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name

  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare

AssertionError  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in
prepare
AssertionError        :     : assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
tassert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
tAssertionErrorAssertionErrorhreadAssertionErrorhread: :
:
tttTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
hreadhreadhread  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in
 main
```

... and so on...

My little code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def display(item):
    print 'item: ' + str(item)


def main():
    items = []
    for i in range(0, 999):
        items.append(i)

    pool = Pool(10)
    pool.map(display, items)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405687/python-2-7-on-windows-assert-main-name-not-in-sys-modules-main-name-for-all

Comment: How are you executing the script? I can't reproduce it on Windows.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Linux either, in Python 2.7.6. Is there any more code that you didn't include in your question?

Comment: @SLawson it is windows bug. No, code is same i have to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @dano it gives such error not always. second script, that i use on same python on windows with multiprocessing.Pool works, except Locks. Seems no way to run it stable on windows :/