# ipython notebooks and multiprocessing.freeze_support()

Tags: windows, python-2.7, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to port code I wrote on Linux to Windows and am having issues with multiprocessing. After adding freeze_support() to my code it runs smoothly from the command line, i.e.

```py
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import myClass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    ## Run some multiprocessing code here.
    c = myCLass()
    c.run()
    ## Done.
```

works just fine.

The code should be used in an ipython notebook in which I switch multiple times between `%pylab inline` and `%pylab qt` (I don't know if this switching matters?).

Running the code within the notebook, i.e. executing

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    ## Run some multiprocessing code here.
    c = myCLass()
    c.run()
    ## Done.
```

in one cell doesn't appear to be doing anything (CPU usage doesn't go up) and the following traceback is printed to the console.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "foo\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
AssertionError: __main__
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16405687/1922650) question, suggesting that it might be a bug. However in my case it does work when run from the command line but not when run through the ipython notebook.

I am using Anaconda with python 2.7 on a Windows 8 machine.

Thanks for hints and explanations to solve this problem!

Comment: I just ported the code to python 3. With Anaconda python 3.4 it runs with no complaints and doesn't even need freeze_support().