# ipython notebook multiprocessing error

Tags: python, ipython

as I wrote on title, I got problem with scikit-learn.

first of all, my dev environment is like below,

- OS : windows7 64bit, python 2.7.9, Anaconda 2.2.0 (64bit),
- ipython/ ipython notebook 3.0.0, scikit-learn 0.15.2

I'm studying scikit-learn and there is KFold cross-validation example like :

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
cross_validation.cross_val_score(svc,X_digits,y_digits,cv=kfold,**n_jobs=-1**)
```

and n_jobs=-1 means that the computation will be dispatched on all the CPUs of the computer. shortly, it's about using multiprocessing I think.

but, when I try to execute this code, I see errors like below

===============================================

```
AssertionErrorassert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
prepare(preparation_data)
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
: AssertionError  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, i
n prepare
AssertionErrorAssertionError_: : : _main_____
_main___main___main__


assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
AssertionError: __main__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
prepare(preparation_data)
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
AssertionError            prepare(preparation_data)
        : prepare(preparation_data)
prepare(preparation_data)
prepare(preparation_data)
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
prepare(preparation_data)
_  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
_main__        AssertionError    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
```

===============================================

I've been tried to search this kind of issues using google but I can't.
Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: Upgrade to Python 3. See this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405687/python-2-7-on-windows-assert-main-name-not-in-sys-modules-main-name-for-all

Comment: oh, thanks for your quick answer. so it means the issue that I asked is known issue and the only way to fix is python version upgrade? I am just afraid that there are some opinions of python 2.7.* is better than 3.* mostly because of useful libraris. but, I cannot judge wether it is right or not...and one more Q : so it means all users with win7 + python 2.7 are experiencing the same problem when multiprocessing code is required?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I'm sorry for my late appreciate comment.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with anaconda 2.3.0 (latest) and python 2.7.9.. cannot upgrade to python 3.0 because of some missing packages.